# How do I combine two tables to just return one field and removing the duplicates

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables with my inventory master data from two different locations but all sitting in one Access database. I need a query where I can create a new table showing all of the inventory codes for both inventory tables, but all duplicates needs to be eliminated. Is this possible and how would I go about it? I don't need all of the other information in the other tables, I am really only looking for the inventory codes.

Comment: Will there be duplicates of the inventory codes in one table or are the inventory codes unique/primary keys?

Comment: There will be duplicates in each table

Comment: I have tried SELECT DISTINCT(STOCK_CODE) FROM TABLE1 UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT(STOCK_CODE) FROM TABLE2 and this returns the values, but I am getting duplicates where the same stock code exists in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select code from table A
union
select code from table B

Once you have the codes, you can use the codes to get the rest of the information from the necessary tables.

Comment: How do I then remove the duplicates?

Comment: I did try the following query:

SELECT STOCK_CODE FROM TABLE 1
UNION ALL
SELECT STOCK_CODE FROM TABLE 2;

However, I am getting duplicate results

Comment: I also tried SELECT DISTINCT(STOCK_CODE) FROM TABLE1 UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT(STOCK_CODE) FROM TABLE2 but I am still getting duplicate values

Comment: https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/union-all/index.htm

Comment: Fantastic, I actually did not know there is a difference between UNION and UNION ALL. All sorted, thank you for your assistance